# Xcode 4.x.x giving error in storyboard after updating it from Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5, ios7, xcode5

I was porting to my existing project to iOS 7 in Xcode 5 framework, But when I opening again in Xcode 4.x.x its giving me this error.

[image]

Comment: Revert the Xcode project file in your git repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have solved it, below are the steps to follow:

**Step I** Right click on your StoryBoard and openAs "SourceCode"

**Step II** [image]

**Step III** Now you are done. open storyboard as interfaceBuilder

Comment: Downgrading like this may work, but it may have unintended side-effects.

Comment: This is a terrible solution!

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 5, the file properties on the right inspector, you can set under what version of Xcode the file should open. You can set this to Xcode 4.6 and it will open in older versions of Xcode.